# mod_python won't "./configure" on BSD

Tags: apache-http-server, python, bsd

I'm trying to install `mod_python` 3.3.1 on Apache 2.4.3 and whenever I try to run `./configure` (with apxs etc), instead of configuring correctly, it says that Apache 2.x is required and my current version is `.`

I've tried on two different versions of Apache, and too different versions of `mod_python` but always with the same result. I am running as root on a FreeBSD system. Any suggestions?

```
\# ./configure --with-apxs=/wwwroot/bin/apxs
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for ar... ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for main in -lm... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking your blood pressure... a bit high, but we can proceed
configure: checking whether apxs is available...
checking for --with-apxs... /wwwroot/bin/apxs executable, good
checking Apache version... ./configure.lineno: /wwwroot/bin/apxs: not found
./configure.lineno: /wwwroot/bin/apxs: not found
./configure.lineno: /: permission denied

configure: error: This version of mod_python only works with Apache 2. The one you have seems to be .
#
```

Comment: To me it looks like it doesn't find apache on the system... so its not `.` its just blank. Can you confirm your apache install was successful?